# Bind MVC confuse

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model, bind, overwrite

I have a view with this code:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.state, Model.States, new { @class = "search" })
```

And a controller with this code:

```
model.state = "MG";
return View("Pageabc",model);
```

This page is called using:

http://localhost.com:58213/Search/Pageabc/?state=SC

See, at controller I set state = MG to bring this value = selected on dropdown, but the dropdown bring value = SC as selected.

What can I do? Tks!

Comment: Are the fields in the view generating any JavaScript that's responding to the query string?

Comment: no David. If i use a breakpoint at view i see Model.State = MG, but show SC as selected. If o remove state=SC from url it works. Tks.

Comment: Is that breakpoint stopping on the server-side processing?  JavaScript happens on the client-side after the server-side code has processed.  One thing you can do is check the page source that's actually returned from the server (not the current state of the page, its original source returned from the server).  What is the value in the HTML in that source?

Comment: i found, its something with modelstate. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9416469/asp-net-mvc-3-dropdownlistfor-fails-when-url-parameter-also-exists-with-same-n

Comment: I guess SC it's the first in the collection, right?

Comment: ModelState will take precedence over the valuse passed in via the model.  This is by design.

Comment: yes, but i tried with "AC" and still the same... the problem is the ModelState always wins. But i cant answer my self ask until 8 hours. Tks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ModelState received the value of state = SC.

The solution:

ModelState.SetModelValue("state", null);